# How may I upload my source package with active ftp over dput to launchpad

Tags: ppa, launchpad

my question is how can I upload my source package ( I already got the .sources file) over the active ftp method with dput to my launchpad ppa?

my .dput.cf file looks as follows:

```
[cooking]
fqdn                    = ppa.launchpad.net
method                  = ftp
incoming                = ~gotwig/lens-cooking/ubuntu/
login                   = anonymous
passive_ftp             = 0
```

my command is

```
dput cooking lens-cooking_0.1_source.changes
```

The traceback is:

```
Good signature on /home/gotwig/lens-cooking_0.1.dsc.
Uploading to cooking (via ftp to ppa.launchpad.net):
Uploading lens-cooking_0.1.dsc: 425 Can't open data connection.
```

It seems to me, as it want to use passive_ftp instead of active one.. I cant use passive ftp becouse of my router.

If there is a way without a configuration file, I would be even more happy.

Comment: Note: I am now using launchpad recipes, so I dont have to use dput in this case.

Answer (score 1):

That config file should get you attempting active FTP, if it doesn't, it may be a bug. Launchpad uploads over both passive and active work for me.

I recommend using sftp, its better all around.

Answer (score 1):

Are you *sure* your router disallows passive FTP? it's usually the other way around, and the trace indicates it has trouble opening the data connection (as opposed to the commands connection) - this further reinforces the belief that the router is also blocking active ftp.

You can use the --passive parameter to dput. As you mention below, active is the default.

If not, you may want to look into using SFTP (assuming it's unblocked by your router) as a transfer method. See here for more details: https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Uploading

Comment: "-P,  --passive  -  use passive ftp instead of active. Note that passive
       ftp is the default unless  specified  otherwise  in  the  configuration
       file." says the man page - clearly

Comment: I'm really sorry, I completely misread. Amended the answer.